# How to get charset of filename

Tags: character-encoding, filenames

Good day, all.

Is there anyway to retrieve charset of filename?

I want to transform charset of a file's name (not include content) to specific encode like UTF-8. But I need the original charset to achieve that.

Any solutions would be appreciated. 
commandline solution even better.

Answer (score 0):

this,you can get the current character set:
    System.getProperty("file.encoding")